# How to make the user input come up as dots in Java

Tags: java

is there any way to display •••'s when a user is typing in the console? My program has a user entering a password for a MySQL database but I want it to show •••'s instead of their password when they type.

Comment: You have no direct control of the console, to the Java process it's just an input stream. If you want asterisks, you'll have to upgrade to a GUI interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Console.readPassword()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--) to disable echoing.  I don't think there's any way to get a substitute character without JNI though.

Answer (score -1):

Dont know about showing "." But instead you can use

**char[] password = console.readPassword("Password? ");**

to input password without echoing on screen.

Comment: Please post the code to this answer so in the event the linked page isn't available this answer will still be useful.

Comment: Thanks Fencer04 for input..